# Change role with rolify with STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, rolify

I'm new in rails and i have a STI that inheritance from user named partner
what i want to do is that user could change their role to partner filling
a form, but i took a registration from devise so when user want to change their role has to fill again the register from devise and put a new email, name, password so how can i do to transfer the user information to partner without creating a completely new user.
or if is there other way to change the role just adding more information to complete the information that a partner needs to be a partner
user only need email, password and name and partner need the same but adding phone number, company, etc.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
rolify
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
           :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>" ,       :thumb => "50x50#"}, :default_url => "/app/assets/images/thumb/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/   

after_create :assign_default_role
  def assign_default_role
    self.add_role(:normal)
  end
end


class Partner < User
  has_many :service
  after_create :assign_partner_role

  def assign_partner_role
    self.add_role(:partner)
  end

end
```